# Getting 404 errors from Google web crawler that are not on my site?

Tags: azure, http-status-code-404, google-search-console

After looking through some of the questions about this, none of them answered my question which is this; I'm getting really weird 404 errors from the Google crawler and they're showing up in my webmaster tools account. If they were simply broken links, it would be easy to fix, but these are not from my site so I have no idea how to fix this.

Keep in mind I have an Azure pay-as-you-go account and it's behind my CloudFlare account. I already contacted CloudFlare and they said to talk to MS about it. I posted it over a week ago in the Azure forums and no answers yet. Also, if I want to put in a ticket to MS Azure I have to buy their $30/month support plan. Before I go that route, I thought I would post here and see what you think.

Here is a screenshot of some of the recent errors

[image]

I have a full CSV file of the errors if you want something more specific.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Pete

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is check your robots.txt file and update it.
http://www.feedthebot.com/ is best site  for identifying broken links.
several other site available like this , they will tell you which link is broken and how to fix this.